# Shell scripting to print out IP address, MAC Address, and default gateway

Tags: awk

I'm trying to write a script that gathers network information with `awk` command.

```
ifconfig enp0s3| grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }'
```

this is the command that I ended up getting to get my IP address, yet I have not figured out how can I write it in a script where I can get an output like this:

```
IP Address : 10.0.2.15
```

I tried

```
echo" IP Address:"$ ifconfig enp0s3| grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }'
```

but I keep getting errors.

Comment: You need a command substitution (`$(...)`) to embed the output from a command in a string: `echo "IP address: $(ifconfig enp0s3| grep "inet " | awk '{gsub("addr:","",$2);  print $2 }')"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk` command to get the IP Address and the MAC Address in a single run. However, the default gateway isn't available via `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig eth0 \
  | awk -F'( *|:)' '{printf "IP Address:  %s\nMAC Address:  %s\n",$16,$7":"$8":"$9":"$10":"$11":"$12}' RS='\n\n'
```

*Output:*

```
IP Address:  10.0.2.15
MAC Address: 00:23:12:f2:56:6d
```